# Java move in an angle between two GPS coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, math, trigonometry

I have a use case where I need to generate GPS coordinates to cover an specific area (marked by a list og GPS coordinates).

So I need to generate coordinates. I have the following functions tested and implemented:

```
//determines wether a Waypoint is inside the specified area
public boolean isInsideArea(Waypoint waypoint)

 public double distanceInKmBetweenGPSCoordinates(Waypoint from, Waypoint to)

 public double[] calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(Waypoint waypoint, double dx, double dy)
```

Here is my naive implementation of how to generate coordinates for a square (or approximately a square):

```
public static List<drone.Waypoint> addAutoGeneratedWaypoints(List<Waypoint> polygon_lat_long_pairs) {
        List<Waypoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();

        AreaTester tester = new GPSPolygonTester(polygon_lat_long_pairs);
        GPSCoordinateCalculator coordinateCalculator = new GPSCoordinateCalculator();
        CustomGPSMapper mapper = new CustomGPSMapper();

        boolean finish = false;
        String mode = "r";
        Waypoint prev = polygon_lat_long_pairs.get(0);
        int count = 0;
        double distanceDown = mapper.distanceInKmBetweenGPSCoordinates(polygon_lat_long_pairs.get(2), polygon_lat_long_pairs.get(3));
        double travelledDown = 0;
        while (!finish) {
            if (mode.equals("r")) {
                double[] nextA = coordinateCalculator.calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(prev.getPosition().getLatitude(), prev.getPosition().getLongitude(), 5.0, 0.0);
                Waypoint next = new DefaultWaypoint(nextA[0], nextA[1]);
                if (tester.isInsideArea(next)) {
                    System.out.println("Waypoint was in area");
                    waypoints.add(next);
                    prev = next;
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Left area, switching position");
                    mode = "l";
                    double[] nextB = coordinateCalculator.calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(prev.getPosition().getLatitude(), prev.getPosition().getLongitude(), 0.0, -3.0);
                    Waypoint next2 = new DefaultWaypoint(nextB[0], nextB[1]);
                    waypoints.add(next2);
                    travelledDown += mapper.distanceInKmBetweenGPSCoordinates(prev, next);
                    prev = next2;
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                double[] nextA = coordinateCalculator.calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(prev.getPosition().getLatitude(), prev.getPosition().getLongitude(), -5.0, 0.0);
                Waypoint next = new DefaultWaypoint(nextA[0], nextA[1]);
                if (tester.isInsideArea(next)) {
                    waypoints.add(next);
                    prev = next;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Left are, switching");
                    mode = "r";
                    double[] nextB = coordinateCalculator.calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(prev.getPosition().getLatitude(), prev.getPosition().getLongitude(), 0.0, -3.0);
                    Waypoint next2 = new DefaultWaypoint(nextB[0], nextB[1]);
                    waypoints.add(next2);
                    travelledDown += mapper.distanceInKmBetweenGPSCoordinates(prev, next);
                    prev = next2;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (travelledDown >= distanceDown) {
                finish = true;
            }
        }

        List<de.dhbw.drone.waypoints.Waypoint> mapped = waypoints.stream().map(p -> new de.dhbw.drone.waypoints.Waypoint(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return mapped;
```

I stop the algorithm when it has travelled down the right/left side of the square.

However, I am struggeling if the shape of the marked area is no square and has sloped lines.

Therefore I would have to move with a bearing, like shown in this image:

[image: Fly with slope]

When I could add this angle to my movement, I could use this algorithm for each shape of area, resulting in the following path:

[image: Desired path]

Can someone help me how to move a distance in meters in this specific angle and how to calculate this angle between two GPS coordinates and how to calculate the angle after turning the side? (right to left instead of left to right and vice versa). Or could this be solved by calculating angle(point1, point2) and angle(point2, point1) ?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate azimuth from one coordinate to another and point at given distancem you can use formulas from [latlong page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (`bearing` and `destination point` sections)

---

You can use the same approach as usually implemented in 2d polygon rasterization.

Horizontal picture lines are continous in memory, so filling horizontal lines is the most reliable way.

In your case you can use, for example, lines at constant latitude.

Sort vertices of your earth polygon by latitude and separate ranges between vertex latitude values, then fill resulting "trapezoids" with point sequences ([plane example](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/rasterization-practical-implementation/rasterization-stage))

Sometimes (complex polygon etc) it would be simpler to use rejection method - generate grid points in escribed rectangle and ignore those outside of polygon.